# PHP while does not return first column from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am novice in scripting and have some issues with my script.
I try to make a table where the script shows the information of my table in the database but the code does not show the first column of the database

script:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM verhuur
                            LIMIT 0 , 30"); //== test

        while ($contract = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
?>

      <TR>
        <TD><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('fietsnummer.php?nummer=<? echo $contract['klantid']; ?>','no','scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=400')"><? echo $contract['klantid']; ?></a></TD>
        <TD><? echo $contract['fietsnummers']; ?></TD>
        <TD><? echo $contract['datumverhuur']; ?></TD>
        <TD><? echo $contract['datumterug']; ?></TD>
        <TD><? echo $contract['borg']; ?></TD>
        <TD><? echo $contract['betaald']; ?></TD>
      </TR>  
 <?
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you double checked the column names? dump the result of your query like this `print_r($contract)` and see what it contains. Also you can access to your data using numeric indexes, like `$contract[0]`

Comment: What is your first column name?

Comment: "PHP while does not return first column from mysql query" Do you mean the column name or the first row of data of your query?

Comment: you need to debug the $contract under while loop and die there. verify if the index has the same name of fietsnummbers

Answer (score 0):

When there are troubles, forget what you see on the browser, instead, inspect the source code, typicaly errors thown by PHP mess HTML and some parts are not shown